# Access to certain domains suddenly stops working

Tags: networking

I am currently using a computer with Linux(Mint) OS at my work place, with a cabled network. Notice, that this is an "unofficial" computer, i.e. not issued by our IT department - but according to IT that is fine.

I now have a problem, that after some months I suddenly cannot access websites at a certain domain. We administrator this server ourselves, so I can see that my requests never reach the server (proxied with a nginx), that is I don't see the requests in the nginx log. This problem, however, only arises when I am on this particular computer within our workplace network. From outside and/or from all computers issued by our IT-department it works fine (even a few RPI's from inside our network).

The weird thing is, however, that this has happened before - but due to another issue I had to reinstall the OS, and then I had access again, until it suddenly stopped again.

I have tried our IT department, but they can not find any reasons why this particular computer shouldn't have access.

Any thought on what might happen due a reinstall that would let me gain access again?

Comment: Do your requests get routed to the proxy?

Comment: No, I don't see anything in the nginx logs.

Comment: Antivirus on the client managing your firewall unexpectedly? You or some other application "managing" your client firewall unexpectedly? Temporary glitch in network routing? What happens if you use a different web browser or even something like `wget`? What about `ping`? Corporate firewall automatically blocking your client because it doesn't conform to expectation?

Comment: Other suggestions (since right now anything is possible) dns resolution? You should check if you can reach the IP address eg: `curl -v --connect-to host:443:ip:443 https://host/` , to rule out DNS. If you get a cert problem, then there's perhaps mitm interception done by the enterprise and you need its cert.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I know this is more or less a blind search.
Good idea with the IP - I cannot reach the IP even. So not a DNS problem.

Both ping, wget and different browsers returns a "No route to host". 

My suspicion is also on some firewall, but my IP department says they don't have entries that should block me. And I still don't understand why a reinstall of the OS then fixed it (for a time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that a docker network was taking up the same IP as my computer had on the network. By deleting it, this issue went away.